# Difficulty with linebreaks/word wrap in cocos2d iPhone/ipad app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to cocos2d and am working on a project where I need to display random text messages (using values from NSString) in the center of the users screen. The messages are appearing like I wanted but now I need to format the text. Most of the messages are fairly long text strings and I want to word wrap them and constrain them to a rectangle in the center of the screen.

Currently I have them positioned using the following code:

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    label2.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
```

This has the messages centered fine, but they extend left and right beyond the screen. I've tried using lineBreakMode: LineBreakModeWordWrap with no
success.

Is there a simple way to constrain the text string within a centered rectangle on the iPad/iPhone/retina devices (similar to positioning with size.width /2)?

Thanks for your help,

Darin

Comment: have you set a CGSize for label2.dimensions to the appropriate boundary you wish the label to respect ?  (assuming a CCLabelTTF)

Comment: I have not. Is there a way to define the boundary in such a way that it would display appropriately on an iPhone an/or iPad (possibly using something like percentages instead of points)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
label2.numberOfLines = 0;
```

This allows the label to extend over multiple lines.

Comment: I tried adding the code you suggested but received the following error: Property 'numberOfLines' not found on object of type 'CCLabelTTF*'

Comment: I tried the code below:

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:randomdidyouknowtext dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30];
label2.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
[self addChild:label2];

I received the following 3 errors/warnings

1. labelWithString dimensions alignment:lineBreakMode:fontName:fontSize' is deprecated

Comment: Here are the last two errors/warnings:

2. Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCTextAlignment' with an rvalue of  ...

3. Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCLineBreakMode' with an rvalue of type '<anonymous...

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CCLabelTTF *l = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"longTextHere" dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30];
l.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
[self addChild:l];
```

version 2.1 look here
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"label" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30 dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75) hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter  lineBreakMode::kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: I tried the suggested code and received the following errors:

1. Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCTextAlignment' with an rvalue of type '<anonymous enum at ..."

Comment: I tried the code below:

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:randomdidyouknowtext dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30];
label2.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
[self addChild:label2];

I received the following 3 errors/warnings

1. labelWithString dimensions alignment:lineBreakMode:fontName:fontSize' is deprecated

Comment: Here are the last two errors/warnings:

2. Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCTextAlignment' with an rvalue of type '<anonymous enum at /Applications...

3. Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCLineBreakMode' with an rvalue of type type '<anonymous enum at /Applications...

Comment: in cocos2d v2.1
use labelWithString:fontName:fontSize:dimensions:hAlignment:lineBreakMode:

or look here for more information
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html

Comment: I tried the following (edited from the documentation you sent)

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        
CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: randomdidyouknowtext
        fontName:@"Arial"
        fontSize:30];
        dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75)
        halignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter
        valignment:kCCVerticalTextAlignmentCenter
       lineBreakMode:kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap
        
        [self addChild:label2 ]  ;

I receive a warning that an ']' is expected and can't run/test. Can you tell me where the error in the code is? Thanks for your help.

Comment: CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"label" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30 dimensions:CGSizeMake(300,75) hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter  lineBreakMode::kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

look at this and compare with urs code